# Sequences only programming language

Tags: programming-languages, language-features, sequences

I once read about a programming laguage which only first-order values were sequences. An integer value, for instance, was seen as a sequence of integers of one element. I totally forgot the name of that language, and the terms i use to search google are too generic, i can't find it. Anyone remembers it? :)

Comment: Sounds like an esoteric language, try finding it here: http://esoteric.voxelperfect.net/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language

Comment: Probably. I tried looking there, but the list is long. In time, i'll find it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Was it Euphoria?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphoria_(programming_language)

Looks like what you were describing based on Wiki article

Comment: I remember that, in the language i'm looking for, every value was a sequence. Euphoria seems to have integers and sequences as values. Thanks anyway!